# Preventing Invoke to freeze form on AddRange

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I got a big database (100,000+) and i need to fill a Combobox with the data from one of the columns

This is the code i have now

```
FastecData db = ConnectionHelper.CreateConnection(CurrentLocation);

List<Fakturor> t = db.Fakturor.OrderBy(z => z.FaktNr).ToList();


List<string> st = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in t)
{
    _busy.WaitOne();
    st.Add(item.FaktNr);
}
st.OrderBy(x => x.Length);

comboBoxFaktNr1.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
    comboBoxFaktNr1.Items.AddRange(st.ToArray());
}));
comboBoxFaktNr2.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
     comboBoxFaktNr2.Items.AddRange(st.ToArray());
}));
```

This is run as a background worker.
The problem i have with this code is that when it runs the `.Items.AddRange(st.ToArray());`
The form stops responding for about 10 sec. Is there a way to prevent the form from freezing?

Comment: If you just need `FaktNr` in the combobox, why are you reading the entire record from the db?

Comment: Are you really adding 100k items to a combobox? why?? The user won't be able to use it! Better store it and then add some values the user has asked for/ filtered out.

Comment: Also if you're using `BackgroundWorker`, what is the purpose of `_busy`?

Comment: Use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke this will run the task async

Comment: Also this line `st.OrderBy(x => x.Length);` has no net effect. You probably wanted to use `Sort`, but even that is not needed.

Comment: The problem i had is that it is saved as a string in the database an was sorted 100 20 3 300 instead of 3 20 100 300. And that was my way of trying to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do all that you're doing in your code:

```
FastecData db = ConnectionHelper.CreateConnection(CurrentLocation);
var t = db.Fakturor.Select(z => z.FaktNr).OrderBy(z => z).ToArray();

comboBoxFaktNr1.Invoke(new Action(() => {
  int x = 0;
  while(t.Length - x > 0)
  {
    var t2 = t.Skip(x).Take(Math.Min(t.Length - x, 1000));
    comboBoxFaktNr1.Items.AddRange(t2);
    comboBoxFaktNr2.Items.AddRange(t2);
    x += 1000;
    Application.DoEvents();
  }
}));
```

But again you should consider that having 100K items in a combobox is a crime against humanity. Consider multi-level filtering to reduce the number of items to a usable size.

Comment: When trying to run this code i get a ´Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'comboBoxFaktNr1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.´ Error. i also had to change it to ´comboBoxFaktNr1.Items.AddRange(t.ToArray());´ to make it even run

Comment: That gives me a `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type` on the Invoke((

Comment: if you are doing so much work, you should consider replacing 'Invoke' with 'BeginInvoke'. And yea: Crime agains humanity ;D

Comment: @Drago87: My bad. Working with multiple languages makes you do simple mistakes. I have fixed it now.

Comment: @Drago87: And yes, @Radinator is right. Try it with `BeginInvoke()` too. You'll get better responsiveness. But then again, you probably don't want your user to interact with the combobox while it is loading.

Comment: That sort of worked. It is faster but the form still lock and i have to use ´t.ToArray()´ for it to work. Also tried BeginInvoke but did not notice any difference.

Comment: Tried taking a screenshot of the form but it was it wont respond until it is done. But everything except the form itself is black until it have filled the combobox

Comment: Changing ´var t = db.Fakturor.Select(z => z.FaktNr).OrderBy(z => z);´ to ´var t = db.Fakturor.Select(z => z.FaktNr).OrderBy(z => z).ToArray();´ made it a bit smoother and the content of the form is no longer black. Still freezes.

Comment: I have now tried loading the form from another form in the background but it freezes the whole program when i do the .AddRange. Is there a better way to do this. With maybe a bindingSorce or something else?

Comment: @Drago87: Did you fix it yet? I have made some changes. See if these fix your problem.

Comment: That works like a charm but went from 14 sec to 45 sec. And i had to `var t2 = t.Skip(x).Take(Math.Min(t.Length - x, 1000)).ToArray();`